# Add value from php (dropdown) in dynamic form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this case, i want to add value from php in javascript, which for dynamic form, but i don't know how to integrate php and javascript

```
$(container).append('<div id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' + ' class="form-group row" style="text-align: center;">'
+ '<div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="keterangan[]" value="Peserta ' + iCnt + ' ' + '">'
+ '<div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="score[]" value="1"></div>'
+ '<div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control select2" name="id[]"><option value=''>-- Pilih --</option>'
// <?php
// foreach ($data_member as $key => $value) {
//  echo "<option value='".$value->id."'>".$value->nama_user."</option>";
// }
// ?>
+ '</select></div>'
+ '</div>');
```

in try using code (line 5-9) but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the echo you can include your + ' since PHP is processed server side. Although mixing server and client side is not the preferred method it should work.

```
    $(container).append('<div id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' + ' class="form-group row" style="text-align: center;">'
    + '<div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="keterangan[]" value="Peserta ' + iCnt + ' ' + '">'
    + '<div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="score[]" value="1"></div>'
    + '<div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control select2" name="id[]"><option value=''>-- Pilih --</option>'
   <?php
     foreach ($data_member as $key => $value) {
      echo "+ '<option value=\"".$value->id."\">".$value->nama_user."</option>'";
     }
     ?>
    + '</select></div>'
    + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS and PHP are loaded at the different times because PHP runs on the server while JS runs on the client so you cannot directly do this. I think you should look into JQuery anfd Ajax for this.

Comment: You can do this, it's just a really bad idea. And you really don't need jQuery and ajax either...

Answer (score 0):

As @dkum suggested you don't really want to mix your client side and server side code.

Try instead creating a container with each in PHP in the HTML making a template and hiding all the content you don't want visible with JS using a class tag on your HTML template.

Then each part of the form can be shown or hidden with the JS depending on what you want there.

Now if you want to 'build a form', just use JS to create the form elements, and then submit to a PHP 'action' ( that's the form elements property, it's sort of a misnomer ) and let the PHP dynamically parse through all the responses in the `$_POST`